# Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'

Tags: react-native, eslint, prettier

I am trying to make ESLint and Prettier work for days but whatever I do, nothing changes.

I don't even know what I installed globally but here is my project's local `package.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.488",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

my `.eslintrc` contains

```
{
  "extends": ["react-app", "plugin:prettier/recommended"]
}
```

And output in ESLint section says

```
[Error - 1:15:10 PM] Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier' Referenced from: /Users/me/project/.eslintrc
```

I have VSCode settings adjusted, so that is fine, but this simple doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

I believe you're missing the main eslint package.
Can you try adding this to your package.json

`"eslint": "^5.8.0",`

Comment: Okay that solved something, but now I see `Cannot find module 'eslint-config-react-app'`

Comment: Ok, I installed all dependencies from errors and now it's working

Comment: This solution works, but any idea how to upgrade. eslint is on `6.7.2` and I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Installing all required packages wasn't enough for me, I also had to restart my IDE (Webstorm).